# bootstrap combobox with append not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, combobox

i have a combo box that needs to append on button click, how can i execute the code `$(document).ready(function(){$('.combobox').combobox();});` in the appended combo box if it is a ready function?

Thank you in advance.

from this site.
https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox/

Comment: Are you trying to append the select/combobox to the dom on button click? Or trying to append something into the select/combobx on button click? (and welcome to stack overflow)

Comment: Im trying to append a select/combobox, but since it is just an appended entity the script ready function is not working, but when i try to create a function that call $('.combobox').combobox();} something wrong happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to call `$('.combobox').combobox();}` *after* appending the new select--it will only run on elements in the dom.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // convert selects already on the page at dom load
  $('select.form-control').combobox();  

  //add selects
  $('#addSelect').click(function(e){
    //create select
    $('<select class="form-control"/>').append('<option>1</option><option>2</option>')
        //add to dom
        .appendTo('#addHere')
        //convert to combobox
        .combobox();
  });
});
```

See [**this demo bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/vvZhda1Mf9) for a functioning example